# What happens to Hubbard chain when perturbation theory blows up? Singular energy for complex interaction

Tags: perturbation-theory, integrable-systems

Consider the spinful Hubbard chain:
$$ H = - t \sum_{i,\sigma} \left( c^\dagger_{i,\sigma} c^{\vphantom \dagger}_{i+1,\sigma} + h.c. \right) + U \sum_n \left( n_{i,\uparrow} - \frac{1}{2} \right)\left( n_{i,\downarrow} - \frac{1}{2} \right). $$

This is Bethe ansatz integrable [1], and its phase diagram is known exactly: for $U=0$ we have two decoupled free-fermion chains (a conformal field theory with central charge $c=2$) whereas for any finite $U>0$, the charges gap out and we have gapless spinons (a conformal field theory with $c=1$; also called a Luttinger liquid). For $U \to \infty$, charges freeze out completely, giving an effective spin-$1/2$ Heisenberg chain.

One can build a perturbation theory around this purely-spin limit, i.e., a perturbation theory in $t/U$. For the ground state energy density, this perturbation theory converges for $t/U < 1/4$; i.e., the radius of convergence for this expansion in $t/U$ is $1/4$. [1]

However, does anything physical happen at this value of the model, i.e., at $U = 4t$? In terms of the field theory description, nothing seems to be special at this point. Is there something special happening in terms of fermionic bound states etc?

In fact, more generally, the exact ground state energy density has branch points in the complex plane for $t/U = \pm i n/4$ (for any $n = 1,2,3,\dots$) [1]. This clearly implies the above radius of convergence, but it still begs the question: is anything physically meaningful happening at $t/U = n/4$? After all, it seems to be the point of the phase diagram beyond which we can no longer effectively describe the low-energy physics as originating from a spin-$1/2$ chain.

[1] *The One-Dimensional Hubbard Model*, Essler et al.